# Implement VisualStudio Gallery like functionality with MEF

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mef

My application uses MEF to provide a nice level of extensibility. Basically, it has a number of interfaces that plugins can implement and they will get imported through the usual MEF mechanics.

However, what I am trying to achieve on the next step is to provide a way from within the application to show me a list of published plugins (hosted somewhere) so a user can choose to download and install these. 
This should be somewhat like the Visual Studio Gallery where Addins/Extensions/Plugins can be downloaded and installed.

I know that I could presumably start writing all of this from scratch. I have also read about several articles revolving around individual topics, such as

- a downloadable plugin would presumably need some type of metadata/manifest with a description, version, etc
- plugins will likely have dependencies - requiring other plugins or plain assemblies and files, so a plugin is more than just the plugin assembly dll -- perhaps a zip file
- checking for updates and downloading these would be needed. I know there are some issues with NET and replacing assemblies while in use
- the downloading and installing would need to deal with permissions. If the app itself was installed into the regular programs folder, then a normal user would perhaps not have rights to throw additional dlls in there

I am not that much concerned about the hosting of available plugins. This could be anything: a network share, a web server - that doesn't matter much.

My question is: does anyone know of a project attempting to do something like this, so I do not have to start from scratch?
Any help would be appreciated.

J.-